# Try and Except statements

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I'm wondering how to make this code flag up 'not a word' if the user types numbers as the answer to this question

```
question=input("What is the capital of England? ")
question=question.lower()

if question==(""):
    print("Empty value")
else:
    try:
        str(question)
    except:
        print("Not a word!")
    else:
        if question==("london"):
            print ("Correct")
        else:
            print ("Wrong")
```

Comment: What's wrong with entering numbers as an answer? When I secede and form the sovereign kingdom of Kevinland, I'm going to name my country's capital "2342". Then your user won't be able to guess all the world's capitals, if you reject digits!

Comment: It's not just specific to this question, i just want to know how to do this for future questions also

Comment: FWIW, apart from the fact that `input()` returns a string, so `question` is already a string, and so `str(question)` just returns a duplicate of that string, it's _very_ unusual for `str(some_object)` to fail: you'd need to create a class that raises an exception in its `__str__` (or `__repr__` method).

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors, but there's no real need for a `try-except` here for your intents and purposes because all input received from the user is *already* a string. `str(question)` will work in nearly any case. You could simply use `.isalpha()` to restrict the input to alpha characters, and an `if-elif-else`:

```
if question==(""):
    print("Empty value")
else:
    if not question.isalpha():
        print("Not a word!")
    elif question == "london":
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Yes, agreed. You should probably mention that all input is received as a string, thus there is no need to try and except.

Comment: question=int(input("What is the Beverly Hills Zip Code? "))

if question==(""):
    print("Empty value")
else:
    if not question.isnumeric():
        print("Not a number")
    elif question == (90210):
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")

Comment: @appreciationsociety Ask your question *in the comments*, please don't suggest it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @appreciationsociety `.isnumeric()` checks a *string* to ensure that it consists only of numeric characters. When you cast the input to an `int` beforehand, this will always be false. When using a built-in method, ensure you read the documentation first so you actually know what it's doing.